# How to compare elements in an array for equality?

Tags: c++, binary, compare

I've come across this problem where I have to transform a number from the decimal system to the binary and compare if the numbers are equal
Example:
7 is becoming 111
The output is false
and where 5 is 101
The output is true
I've figured out how to transform the numbers with an array
But have no idea how to compare them

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    int arr[8] = {};
    if ((num >= 0) && (num <= 255))
    {
        while (num != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                if (num % 2 == 0)
                    arr[i] = 0;
                else
                {
                    arr[i] = 1;
                }
                num = num / 2;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
            cout << arr[i];
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "error" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What part of your code isn't doing what you want it to do? You look like you have the code to "transform" a number into its "binary" representation, but I don't see where you want to do the comparison.

Comment: Since you're the one doing the transformation - aren't the numbers always trivially equivalent?

Comment: To check if an 8-element array of 1's and 0's represents a given integer, you either transform the integer into an 8-element array of 1's and 0's, and compare each element piecemeal; or you transform the 8-element array of 1's and 0's into its integer representation and compare if the two integers are equal.

Comment: Please explain how decimal 5 and binary 101 – both representing the number five – are equal, while decimal 7 and binary 111 – both representing the number seven – are not.

Comment: It's actually that the program have to see if the binary code is consistently identical for the number and if it is is shall output false, and if there is any difference shall output true (see the example).

Comment: Sorry, but still I didn't get the question, which two numbers are to be compared? I suppose your are trying to compare the bits of a integer number converted into binary. Please explain the question more clearly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.